# Reverse geocoding problem

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-server, reverse-geocoding

[image]

[image]

[image]

I did an address locator on ArcMap and I published the geocode service on ArcGIS Server. When entering the long/lat I got the address but when trying the reverse geocode it didn't get the address.

Comment: Could you please add the error message as text, not picture?

Comment: I'm not familiar with these tool but I wonder what the Output Spatial reference (4326) do when you request an adresse (or should it be Input Spatial reference) ? Also if you work in a geographic CRS are you sure that the distance parameter is not interpreted as degree ?

Answer (score 0):

- As per the following documentation, the search tolerance is only 10 meters https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/geocode/api-reference/geocoding-reverse-geocode.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_38FA9E7038A64F54B34EB9CCBBCC92AD
- You are attempting to pass a "distance" parameter with the request to increase this search tolerance, however, "distance" is not a supported parameter for ReverseGeocode requests.
- The distance parameter is deprecated and no longer recognized by the geocoding service.

Comment: i modified the distance params but i still have the same problem,, while when i do the same work with the web Mercator projection it works